How to plot a small matrix-like data in R or ggplot2
I have a small matrix like DATA below where for each row on variable Challenge there is a count on the subsequent columns showing how many people responded from "I don't know" to "Very challenging" to that challenge.
The goal is to show these counts on a plot for all challenges.
I wonder if there is a plotting function in base R or ggplot2 can represent this data in a single plot?
DATA <- structure(list(Challenge = c("Obtaining  documents from the student's previous school2", 
"Authenticating obtained documents 2", "Translating the documents into English2", 
"Conducting schooling history interviews or other methods to obtain non-transcript course history information2", 
"Administering assessment for placement or proficiency-based credit2", 
"Evaluating course equivalency; what credit will be awarded for prior work2", 
"Making placement decisions", "Lack of clarity around process, practices, roles, or responsibilities", 
"Your own understanding of what is recorded on the transcript"
), `I don't know` = structure(c(16L, 32L, 20L, 22L, 32L, 17L, 
15L, 18L, 11L), dim = 9L, class = "table", dimnames = list(NULL)), 
    `Not at all challenging` = structure(c(7L, 20L, 46L, 27L, 
    28L, 22L, 21L, 34L, 47L), dim = 9L, class = "table", dimnames = list(
        NULL)), `Somewhat challenging` = structure(c(86L, 67L, 
    85L, 80L, 64L, 93L, 110L, 65L, 90L), dim = 9L, class = "table", dimnames = list(
        NULL)), `This is not a part of our process` = structure(c(2L, 
    12L, 1L, 18L, 31L, 8L, 6L, 1L, NA), dim = 9L, class = "table", dimnames = list(
        NULL)), `Very challenging` = structure(c(69L, 49L, 28L, 
    33L, 25L, 40L, 28L, 62L, 32L), dim = 9L, class = "table", dimnames = list(
        NULL))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))


I think a Likert-style plot would be appropriate here:
library(tidyverse)

DATA %>%
  lapply(as.vector) %>%
  as.data.frame(check.names = FALSE) %>%
  pivot_longer(-1, names_to = "Response") %>%
  mutate(Challenge = stringr::str_wrap(Challenge, 30),
         Response = factor(Response, names(DATA)[c(6, 4, 3, 2, 5)])) %>%
  ggplot(aes(value, Challenge, fill = Response)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous("Number of responses", expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral") +
  theme_minimal(16) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_line())



If you have the latest version of tidyverse, plus stringr, then the exact code above will work with the exact input in your question. Can you be more specific when you say "don't wrap correctly"? Do you mean they don't wrap at all, or you get an error, or a warning, or they wrap but don't space nicely, or they break at different points, or something else I haven't mentioned?

Do you have stringr installed?

Fixed it, it was a typo! BTW, can we also add percentages next to the counts that show in the plot?

Of course.  Instead of label = value inside geom_text, try label = paste0(value, "(", scales::percent(value / 180), ")")

Awesome, if I may, why divide by 180?

That's the total number of respondents in your data

A small multiples plot would be best IMO:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DATA |>
  dplyr::mutate(across(-Challenge, as.integer)) |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = -Challenge,
    names_to = "name", 
    values_to = "value", 
    ) |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    name = factor(
      name, 
      levels = rev(
        c( "Not at all challenging", "Somewhat challenging", "Very challenging",
          "This is not a part of our process", "I don't know")
        ))) |>
  ggplot(aes(y = name, x = value)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), hjust = 0, nudge_x = 1) +  
  facet_wrap(~Challenge) 


# this version shows percentages

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(scales)

DATA |>
  # counts are integer
  dplyr::mutate(across(-Challenge, as.integer)) |>
  # one observation per row
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = -Challenge,
    names_to = "name", 
    values_to = "value", 
    ) |>
  # order the levels of the factor to sort the bars on the y-axis
  dplyr::mutate(
    name = factor(
      name, 
      levels = rev(
        c( "Not at all challenging", "Somewhat challenging", "Very challenging",
          "This is not a part of our process", "I don't know")
        ))) |>  
  # replace NA values with 0
  tidyr::replace_na(list(value = 0)) %>%
  # calaculate opercentages per challenge
  dplyr::mutate(.by = Challenge, pct = value/sum(value)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = pct, y = name)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::label_percent(accuracy = .1)(pct)), hjust = 0, nudge_x = 0.02) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent(), breaks = seq(0, 1, .2), limits = c(0,1)) +
  facet_wrap(~Challenge) 


fun variant on a likert scale, but with columns that allows comparisons
  ggplot(aes(x = pct, y = stringr::str_wrap(Challenge, 24))) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = name)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  facet_wrap(~name, nrow = 1)


Thank you! Two things, first, can we have the plot titles and y-axis titles switch places? Second, can we have the values show to the right of the horizontal bars?

Swap the titles and y-axis? I don't understand. To add the values, use geom_text(aes(label = value), hjust = 0, nudge_x = 1) +

Also, instead of count, can we display percentages in each panel next to the counts?

I have added a version that shows percentages.
